# Passing parameters while intent-based navigation in List Report

Tags: abap, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide, cds

In my list report, when I click directly on the 'Document Number' field it opens another app but doesn't pass values. Only when I click the arrow on the right and move to 'General Information', then in this section when I click on the field, the value is passed and right document is opened. Is it possible to make it work with direct click on the report field?
[image: Report]
[image: General Information]
[image: CDS view definition]

If this is not possible, can you advise me how to change the logic in CDS to get "quick view" pop up appear after the click in which this hotspot can work for sure (attached screen from standard App where it works).
[image]

Comment: Having the same issue.. any help?

Comment: @Merve: URL and field naming in CDS was a key in my case. Check the url in working app and compare with your case. Look at parameters name(s).

Comment: can you please describe your solution in more detail for common use?